# What are the memory and performance impacts of importing a given module from the python standard library?

Tags: python, module, scripting

For example, if I can avoid using re.py for a string substitution operation, will not loading the 13k(+/-) module result in significantly improved script performance?

Comment: Do you have a specific module in mind, or just generally asking? Do you have any memory restrictions. Most modules don't take up any noticeable amount of memory and are only imported once and fairly quickly. Frankly, I'd be more concerned about the performance of my algorithm than importing some module.

Comment: Unlikely; I'd wager you'd see more improvements with better algorithms. You might be able to get a free performance boots with [pypy](http://pypy.org/) - the [JIT compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) takes a few to "warm up," but once it does it's really fast.

Comment: @Reti43 Yes, I was referring to the 're' module which source is approximately 13k.  No memory restrictions, but it makes me sick to think of loading a 13k module into memory when I can replace it with a half dozen lines of code.

Comment: I think a better question is which choice will yield fewer bugs in your code. I use `re` when doing so is easier and more provable for me than using `.split()`, `.index()`, etc. Conversely, I use `.split()` when doing so is easier and more provable.

Answer (score 0):

The performance effect is minimal. On my middle-of-the-road PC, I ran the following command:

```
$ time python -mre

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.017s
sys 0m0.005s
```

Since the entire process of loading Python, running the Python interpreter, **and** importing `re` took only 0.02s, the cost of importing `re` is clearly smaller than `.02s`.

EDIT:

Further testing with `time python -c 'exit()'` indicates that doing nothing takes the same amount of time as `import re`. To put it another way, the cost of `import re` is not measurable.

Comment: That's incredible.  I guess my concern is not practical, but more a matter of principle.